# Can I travel within the Schengen area while my Italian residency card is being renewed?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, schengen, denmark, permesso-di-soggiorno

I am a Filipina living legally here in Italy. My permesso di soggiorno is under renewal since it has been expired. I was scheduled for biometrics on April 11 and I have to go to Denmark on April 28. I am afraid I will not be allowed to go to denmark with only the receipt from the Posta,., or can i travel to denmark with only the receipt from posta? Are there ways in which I can travel or alternative ways to do?

Comment: What or where is Timbro?

Comment: "Timbro" is the term used when you have applied for a renewal of residence permit and was scheduled for thumbmark.  After this you have to wait for the release for the new permit to stay.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83623/travel-while-residence-permit-has-expired-but-is-being-renewed

Comment: Have you applied for a visa for the Denmark trip?

Comment: Have not applied for visa for denmark because they say I can not apply for danish visa while i am renewing my permit to stay in italy.

Answer (score 1):

Timatic, the database used by airlines, states the following regarding [**Italy itself**](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=ph&DE=it&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=it&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX):

> Residents of Italy holding expired Residence Permits or a
>     copy of an expired Residence Permit  are permitted to
>     re-enter Italy, provided also holding **a receipt issued by
>     the Italian Post Office or Police Department**, confirming new
>     permit has been applied for. Applications for renewal must
>     be made within 60 days of expiring, otherwise immigration
>     could refuse re-entry, even if holding confirmation of
>     application. Holders copies of an expired Residence Permit
>     also require a statement, stating that they are holding a
>     copy.
>     Residence Permits that include a named child must be valid
>     when traveling with the named child.

This is **not** stated for [**Denmark**](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=ph&DE=dk&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=it&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX)

However, if you travel by **air** and avoid Ryanair, the chance of being caught by authorities or stopped from flying is next to none - if checking in bags, simply present your passport for them to match you against the ticket, and the same thing if asked to present ID at the gate (only likely with easyJet).

In other words, do **not** travel by land, as Denmark has re-introduced selective border checks at the land border and ferry ports, and Switzerland (which you would likely pass through) has them as well.

Comment: Isn't Denmark currently conducting systematic checks at airports as well due to the refugee crisis?

Comment: @JonathanReez No they're not (at all), and it's not even systematic at the land border.

Comment: Would be nice if we could make a canonical answer for Schengen area as a whole.