# Can I leave Italy to non Schengen Area (Cyprus) with direct flight while I'm waiting for my first permesso di soggiorno?

Tags: schengen, italy, cyprus, permesso-di-soggiorno, residence-permits

I'm from Ukraine and I'm waiting for my **first** permesso di soggiorno (family reunification, not a refugee). I have a **ricevuta** (receipt issued by Italian Post office), already submitted my fingerprints and need to wait near 8 more months to receive permesso. I'm already in Italy for 4 months.

Can I leave Italy and travel to non Schengen Area, especially Cyprus (my passport allows me to visit Cyprus) with direct flight from Italy ? And after 7-8 month come back and receive my permesso ? Because I read that if you are waiting for the **first** permesso, you cannot leave Italy at all, and if you leave, then they can cancel your permesso.

Thanks

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I've read tons of posts in different websites and in some of them there was this information.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. However, [the answer to this previous question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88224/can-i-travel-within-the-schengen-area-while-my-italian-residency-card-is-being-r) quotes TIMATIC (the [IATA](http://www.iata.org/) document reference commonly used by airlines) as saying only renewing holders or applicants can re-enter Italy after travel, thereby suggesting that one waiting for a **first** permesso cannot re-enter Italy.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica yeah, but I plan to stay out of Italy for 7-8 months and I'll be able to come back using my passport (when I'll gain 90 / 180 days in Schengen area).

Comment: Roma, is your family member in Italy an EU citizen or a citizen of an EEA country or of Switzerland?

Comment: If leaving does not make your application abandoned, staying outside Italy for 7 or 8 months certainly is ground to refuse (the renewal) of a residence permit.

Comment: @phoog no, they only have permanent residency

Answer (score 2):

La [polizia del Stato](https://www.poliziadistato.it/articolo/10722) (who deals with residence permit) states :

> > The same facilitated procedure is granted to foreigners who have submitted their application for their **first** residence permits for
> > **employment, self-employment, or family reunification**, provided that:
>
> - they leave and re-enter Italy through any Italian external border crossing point (cicular letter 11th March 2009);
> - they show their passport or other equivalent travel document, along with the entry visa specifying the reasons of their stay (employment,
>   self-employment, or family reunification ) and the receipt issued by
>   Italian Post offices (Poste Italiane S.p.A.);
> - they do not transit through other Schengen countries, as this is not allowed.

Now, leaving for 7-8 months, will likely make it extremely suspicious on re-entry.

This is made for small temporary trips, you may have issues at the border, as a residence permit is made for residence.

A more than a few-weeks absence will raise eyebrows, and maybe prevent eventual renewal or even lead to pure and simple revocation, I can't find for Italy but usually 6 months out of country will invalidate your residence permit