# Possibility to travel to Cyprus (Larnaca) with permesso di soggiorno

Tags: schengen, eu

Can I travel to Cyprus (Larnaca) with a permesso di soggiorno? I am a student in Italy. I have booked a flight for tonight. Could you answer me quickly?

Comment: Does this help? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178132/can-i-leave-italy-to-non-schengen-area-cyprus-with-direct-flight-while-im-wai